# Taylor expanding a matrix exponential in terms of a parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

As part of my research, I had to compute a Taylor expansion of the period map of an ODE system. The period map I obtained was of the form
$$ P(z) = \exp(f(\delta)S)z$$
where $S$ is the matrix associated with my ODE system's linearization, $\dot{z} = Sz$, and $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is an analytic function in the parameter $\delta$ (used for continuation).

My problem was to write out $P(z)$ as a Taylor series in $\delta$, which I ended up doing by hand and finding $P(z) = z + O(\delta^2)$. But now in hindsight I realize there probably is a way to compute the series from the above expression for $P$ in terms of the derivatives of $f$.

Is that the case? How could I compute this expansion without directly writing the entries of the exponential? Note that $f(\delta)$ is the only occurrence of $\delta$ in the expression for $P$, and I am not concerned about issues of convergence. Also note that I want the series in powers of $\delta$, not of $S$. Thanks!

Comment: Do we have $f(0) = 0$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes--$f$ is of the form $f(\delta) = c_1\delta^2 / (c_2 + c_3\delta^2)$

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking the expansion should go like this: we have by definition of the matrix exponential,
$$ 
\exp(f(\delta)S) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{[f(\delta)S]^n}{n!}.
$$
We know this converges for all $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$, so because $f$ is analytic and the above entry functions are power series in $f(\delta)$, they converge uniformly (as we vary $\delta$).

Thus we may interchange the derivative and the sum, yielding
$$
\frac{d}{d\delta}\left(\exp(f(\delta)S)\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d}{d\delta}\left(\frac{[f(\delta)S]^n}{n!}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n[f(\delta)]^{n-1}f'(\delta)S^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f'(\delta)S\left(\frac{[f(\delta)S]^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right)\\
= f'(\delta)S\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{[f(\delta)S]^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right) = f'(\delta)S\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{[f(\delta)S]^n}{n!}\right)  = f'(\delta)S\exp(f(\delta)S).
$$
We could put the $S$ on the right too. If correct this reasoning gives that the second derivative is
$$
\frac{d^2}{d\delta^2}(\exp(f(\delta)S)) = \left(f''(\delta)S + [f'(\delta)S]^2\right)\exp(f(\delta)S)
$$
and so on.

In my case, since $f(\delta) = \frac{c_1\delta^2}{c_2 + c_3\delta^2}$, I have $f(0) = 0, f'(0) = 0$, and $f''(0) = 2c_1/c_2$. Therefore the desired expansion ought to be
$$
P(z) = \exp(f(\delta)S)z = \left(\exp(f(0)S) + \delta f'(0)S\exp(f(0)S) + \frac{\delta^2}{2}\left(f''(0)S + [f'(0)S]^2\right)\exp(f(0)S) + O(\delta^3)\right)z
= \left(I +  0 + \frac{\delta^2}{2}\left(\frac{2c_1}{c_2}S\right) + O(\delta^3)\right)z = z + \frac{\delta^2c_1}{c_2}Sz + O(\delta^3).
$$
I believe this matches what I derived by hand--I will have to double check. Does this work look correct?